FabricJS Adding TAB character to a Textbox
I am trying to implement a way to add a TAB character (or even multiple spacebar characters) when the TAB key is pressed while editing a Textbox.
Unfortunately, I have two solutions and neither seems to work. They result in the same unintended behavior: Hitting TAB initially seems to work, until you add any other character during the edit, at which point all of the characters added by the TAB key have been reverted.
I'm not sure why this is happening or what a fix could be. I tried digging into the internal private methods and have not found anything that seems to cause this yet.
While I'm here, a bonus would be if someone could help me get the TAB character to actually appear with a character width of 4. Currently, the tab character looks identical to a regular space when inside the Textbox.
ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var textbox_options = {
    editable: true,
    hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
};
var text = new fabric.Textbox('some text', textbox_options);
canvas.add(text);
canvas.requestRenderAll();

function addTab(textbox) {
    var t = textbox.text;
    var selStart = textbox.selectionStart;
    textbox.set('text', t.substring(0, selStart) + 't' + t.substring(selStart, t.length));
    textbox.setSelectionStart(selStart+1);
    textbox.setSelectionEnd(selStart);
}

// solution 1
fabric.Textbox.prototype["insertTabChar"] = function (e) {
    addTab(this);
}
text.keysMap[9] = "insertTabChar";

// solution 2
this.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    if (event.code == "Tab") {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
fabric.IText.prototype.onKeyDown = (function(onKeyDown) {
    return function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            addTab(this);
            canvas.requestRenderAll();
        }
        onKeyDown.call(this, e);
    }
})(fabric.IText.prototype.onKeyDown);


I had the same problem as you.
I think you can successfully implement the tab key functionality if you write code like below.
// Set Canvas And Textbox
const textbox_options = {
  editable: true,
  hasBorders: false,
  hasControls: false,
  lockMovementX: true,
  lockMovementY: true,
};

const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
const text = fabric.Textbox('Example Text', textbox_options);
canvas.add(text);
canvas.requestRenderAll();

// Define addTab function
const addTab = (textbox) => {
  const t = textbox.text;

  // Split Textbox Sentences into Lines
  const textLineList = selectedText.text.split(/(?<!\/)n/);

  // Add \t to First Sentence Only
  // You can replace '\t' with four space characters ('    ')
  textLineList[0] = '\t' + textLineList[0];

  //Rejoin Split Sentences
  textbox.set('text', textLineList.join(''));
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
};


// Eventhandler that Operates When the Tab Key is Pressed,
// Canvas Exists, and the Selected Object Type is a Textbox.
const tabKeyDownHandler = (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 90 && canvas?.getActiveObject().type === 'textbox') {
    addTab(canvas.getActiveObject());
  }
};

// Register event handler
document.addEventListener('keydown', tabKeyDownHandler);

Since I actually wrote the code the way I applied it to my project, there may be a better way.
I hope it was helpful to you. Thank you :)

Oh, by the way, this code only adds tab to the first line. To add a tab to the current cursor operation, you need to adjust the index of textLineList.

Is this for v6+? I'm currently on v5.3, this doesn't seem to work. I can't even get tabKeyDownHandler to fire while in editing mode, let alone addTab.

Ah, you are using v5.3. My solution is for v6+. Sorry for not being of help.
